# jQuery Frozen DIv Header with Fade in Notification Bar

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-position

I have a frozen div (frozen using css position: fixed; property) that is serving as a header for a web site. Right after the div (or under the div) is the body or rest of the webpage.

A notification bar will fade in using

```
 jQuery ($bar).fadeIn(6000).delay(4900).fadeOut();
```

This jQuery will run every 24 seconds by a Javascript `setInterval` function.

My issue is that the content right under the frozen div is set to a padding-top: 36px to insure that the frozen div does not cover or display over the body. The issue will occur when the notification div is faded in. When this happens the height will change (technically) and the content of the header will hover over the body. How do I get the body to move down, or not be covered over?

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery's `Prepend()` method before the `body` tag for the Frozen div

**See my example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uday99/XYJBy/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('bodyID').style.marginTop = height-of-header+'px';
```

Then when bar faded in:

```
document.getElementById('bodyID').style.marginTop = whatever-it-needs-to-be+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `relative` then `absolute` positioning; wrap your body content in a block-level element (like a `div`), then make the `position` of your body content `relative` and set the `top` property to `36px`

```
<div id="header">
    <!--
    *   Site banner
    -->
</div>
<div id="body_wrapper">
    <div id="body_content">
        <!--
        *   Page content
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    /*  Other styles */
}
#body_wrapper {
    position:relative;
    /*  Other styles */
}
#body_content {
    position:absolute;
    top:36px;
    /*  Other styles */
}
```

Just implement the CSS into your existing style sheet.